# What is $\Bbb{Z}^2$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

$\Bbb{Z}$ is the set of all integers, but what does it mean to square the set? Is it to multiply the set by itself? Or does it just mean that every integer in $\Bbb{Z}$ is now square, so

$$\Bbb{Z} = \{1, 2, 3, ...\} \implies \Bbb{Z}^2= \{1, 4, 9, 16,...\}$$

If this is the case, would $\Bbb{Z}^2$ just be $\Bbb{N}^2$?

Comment: It can be either depending on context, but usually it means the set of ordered pairs of integers.

Comment: Here’s a [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: For your other question: is $\mathbb{Z^2}$ just $\mathbb{N^2}$? No, becuase $\mathbb{N} \subseteq \mathbb{Z}$ which means $\mathbb{N^2} \subseteq \mathbb{Z^2}$. Why? I'll leave that up to you. Hint: suppose $(a,b) \in \mathbb{N^2}$. What's their relation with $\mathbb{Z^2}$?

Answer (score 4):

It means the cartesian product. As in $$\Bbb Z^n = \underbrace{\Bbb Z \times \cdots \times \Bbb Z}_{\mbox{n times}}.$$In particular $$\Bbb Z^2 = \{ (a,b) \mid a,b \in \Bbb Z \}.$$

Comment: So the set would go: (0, 1), (0, 2),...   and then so on for (1, y), (2, y),...(x,y) ?

Comment: Pick any pair $(x,y)$, and ask: are both $x$ and $y$ integers? If yes, it belongs to $\Bbb Z^2$. If one of them is not an integer, the pair does no belong to $\Bbb Z^2$. For example, $(-1,3) \in \Bbb Z^2$, $(1/2, 0) \not\in \Bbb Z^2$.

Comment: @LtotheV - yes, that's right, except you can't really think about it as an "order". Plus, it's the integers, so either x or y can be negative.

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't. If you have two sets $A$ and $B$, then the cartesian product of those sets is defined by: $$A \times B:=\{ (a,b):a \in A, b \in B \}.$$ This is, $A \times B$ is the set whose elements are ordered pairs (the first coordinate is an element of $A$ and the second coordinate is an element of $B$). If $A=B$, then we write $A^2:=A \times A$.

For example: $$\mathbb{R}^2=\{ (x,y):x,y \in \mathbb{R} \}.$$ Also $$\mathbb{N}^2:=\{ (m,n):m,n \in \mathbb{N} \}$$ and $$\mathbb{Z}^2=\{ (k,l):k,l \in \mathbb{Z} \}.$$